# CSS image not properly sized

Tags: html, css, image

I have this paralax image on my website (the big nature one)
[This is how the page is normally seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GedZ5.jpg)

But its not properly sized. When i open chrome dev tools it looks like the image below and that's how i want it to be.
[this is the image how it needs to be (the nature image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7X8W.jpg)

so what i want: I want the nature image seen on the pics above to be shown as it is in the second picture (with devtools). I know that the image is not properly sized for the box. But i don' t know how to fix it and can' t find something on the internet.

Can someone help me?
If my question is not clear enough please reply what i should add!

My CSS code attached to the image-paralax:

```
 .header{
        background-image: url("nav-bg.png"); //The background image
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    
    .parallax-2 {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="header parallax-2">
        <div class="logo fade-in-3"><img src="logo.png" alt="BeldrProductions" width="500"></div>
        <!-- The nav-items go here. but i left them out to save space-->
</div>
```

Hope to see your answer soon!
Beldr

Note:
Suggestions from the answers below:

- background-size: contain no-repeat; (does not work)
- object-fit: contain and object-fit: cover (does not work)
- width&height 100% (nope)

My code on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BeldrProductions/k5f70dy9/

Comment: have you tried putting it as background image? if not then put it as bg and use property background-size: contain no-repeat; and see the results.

Comment: Does not work. The text under it shifted a bit but thats all. the image is still the same

Comment: try adding object-fit: contain and object-fit: cover in your image class

Comment: nope still the same.

Comment: have you tried fixing the image size? height: 100%; (according to div) and width: 100%;

Comment: bdw [link](https://i.ibb.co/wszdgDf/nav-bg.jpg) this is the complete image. and i want the content in the center of it to show in the div.

Comment: sorry, but still the same

Comment: @BeldrProductions can you share your code in jsfiddle or stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that has helped me. But i just used it without a image

Thanks, Bye!

if there still is anyone who has a solution. Please leave it below. I would love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your background image container in another div.
Check the HTML, CSS snippets along with screenshot.

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="parallax-2">
        <div class="logo fade-in-3">
          <img src="logo.png" alt="BeldrProductions" width="500" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- The nav-items go here. but i left them out to save space-->
    </div>
</body>

 <style>
  .header {
    height: 300px;
    width: inherit;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  }
  .parallax-2 {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    background-image: url("nav-bg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
</style>
```

[image: Image with full screen. Without dev tool]

[image: Image with dev tool open]

Comment: [link](https://i.ibb.co/64nnNhg/image.png) dont think this is supposed to happn :/

Comment: isnt there any way of changing the way the image is displayed? I can crop the image but then the resolution is p**p. And bdw the logo was fine. i only need to change the background